# How to install Climate Data Operator (CDO) into Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, cdo-climate

I'm trying to install cdo onto Anaconda via conda-forge however I'm getting "PackagesNotFoundError".

I've tried all the options listed here (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cdo) and get the same error. The same even when running the .tar.gz file. Is there any way to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: I installed it with `conda install -c conda-forge python-cdo xarray` (i added `xarray` as it was required).

Comment: Thanks. I think it was because I was trying to do it through Windows. Worked through Ubuntu.